# How create new tag before end tag with condition with java StAX?

Tags: java, xml, stax

I have two `xml`. I read data from second `xml` and save to first `xml`. I hold dates from second `xml` in `LinkedHashMap`.

I have machines list in first `xml`. This machines have tags with id that is key from `LinkedHashMap`. I want to add new tag before end `</machine>` tag only if this machine id exist in `LinkedHashMap`.

```
 while (xmlEventReader.hasNext()){
                XMLEvent xmlEvent = xmlEventReader.nextEvent();
                xmlEventWriter.add(xmlEvent);

                if (xmlEvent.isStartElement()){
                    StartElement startElement = xmlEvent.asStartElement();
                    xmlPath.addLast(startElement.getName().getLocalPart());
                    currentPath = join(xmlPath);
                    XMLEvent xmlModEvent;

                                switch (currentPath){
                                    case "/scbm-extract/machineList/machine/resourceCode":
                                        resourceCodeForMachine = xmlEventReader.peek().asCharacters().getData();
                                        break;
                                    case "/scbm-extract/machineList/machine":
                                        if (attributeIdealSequences.containsKey(resourceCodeForMachine))
                                            createTextElement("applyIdealSequence", "yes", xmlEventWriter, xmlEventFactory);
                                        break;
```

My code create new tag but This tag is in wrong place and wrong machine(next tag, next machine) The tag is after open `<machine>` I expect this tag before end tag `</machine>`. I want to add new tag after `<shiftCalendarList>`.
`resourceCode` is id in `LinkedHashMap` [image]